# AngularJs directives cleanup

Tags: angularjs

I've been reading about AngularJS directives and as stated in [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), best practice to avoid memory leaks is to cleanup. I don't understand what is exactly cleaned up by angular, and what should I cleanup myself (using `$destroy`).

This is the most exact thing I could find:

> Listeners registered to scopes and elements are automatically cleaned
>   up when they are destroyed, but if you registered a listener on a
>   service, or registered a listener on a DOM node that isn't being
>   deleted, you'll have to clean it up yourself or you risk introducing a
>   memory leak.

So, I can understand from this the answer for listeners, but i'm not sure about other things that might need to be cleaned up (for example, variables and object I created on the directive's scope). Are things other than 'scopes and elements listeners' cleaned by angular or should I clean them myself?

Comment: you should clean rootscope events or any timeout and interval set in the page

Comment: those are service listeners, so according to quote should be cleaned. my question is about things other than listeners